# Java recursive deep cloning

Tags: java, deep-copy, avl-tree

Good evening.

I'm trying to implement an AVL Tree and have an issue copying nodes in the rotation process:

- If I do it with a shallow copy, a rather predictable mayhem ensues.
- If I do it with a manual deep copy, I can only copy the direct attributes of the object (node), but not its deeper levels.
  To clarify, if I have a Node that has 2 children which themselves have 1-2 children and whose children might have children of their own,... I can only copy the initial Node and its direct children, but lose the grandchildren and further descendants.

So, I'd like to know if there is a way to go around that limitation.
Here is the full code of the class (the main is just a call to initialise()), everything else behaves correctly, so if I could just manage to copy the Nodes correctly in the rotations, I would have a working AVL Tree.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NodeQ
{
static boolean isEmpty=true;
private int h=1;
private double x, y;
private ArrayList<Segment> segmentsStarting=new ArrayList<Segment>();
private NodeQ left=null, right=null;

public NodeQ(double abs, double ord) {x=abs; y=ord;}
public NodeQ(NodeQ Q) {this.x=Q.x; this.y=Q.y; this.segmentsStarting=Q.segmentsStarting;}

public double getX() {return x;}
public double getY() {return y;}
public NodeQ getLeft() {return left;}
public NodeQ getRight() {return right;}
public ArrayList<Segment> getSegmentsStarting() {return segmentsStarting;}
public int getH(){return h;}

public void setX(double abs) {x=abs;}
public void setY(double ord) {y=ord;}
public void setLeft(NodeQ l) {left=l;}
public void setRight(NodeQ r) {right=r;}
public void addSegment(Segment s) {segmentsStarting.add(s);}

public void calcH()
{
    if (this.left!=null)
    {
        if (this.right != null)
        {
            if (this.left.h > this.right.h) this.h = this.left.h + 1;
            else this.h = this.right.h + 1;
        }
        else this.h = this.left.h + 1;
    }
    else if (this.right!=null) this.h=this.right.h+1;
}

public void initialise(Segment segment)
{
    if (NodeQ.isEmpty)
    {
        y=segment.yUpper; 
        x=segment.xUpper;
        addSegment(segment); 
        setLeft(new NodeQ(segment.xLower, segment.yLower));
        h=2;
        NodeQ.isEmpty=false;
    }
    else
    {
        insert(segment.xUpper, segment.yUpper, true, segment);
        insert(segment.xLower, segment.yLower, false, segment);
    }
}

public void deepCopy(NodeQ Q)
{
    this.x=Q.x;
    this.y=Q.y;
    this.segmentsStarting=Q.segmentsStarting;
    if (Q.left==null)this.left=null;
    else this.left=new NodeQ(Q.left);
    if (Q.right==null) this.right=null;
    else this.right=new NodeQ(Q.right);
}

public void insert(double abs, double ord, boolean isUpperEndpoint, Segment s)
{
    if (y>ord || (y==ord && x<abs))
    {
        if (left==null)
        {
            left=new NodeQ(abs, ord); 
            if (isUpperEndpoint) addSegment(s);
        }
        else left.insert(abs, ord, isUpperEndpoint, s); 
    }
    else
    {
        if (right==null)
        {
            right=new NodeQ(abs, ord);
            if (isUpperEndpoint) addSegment(s);
        }
        else right.insert(abs, ord, isUpperEndpoint, s);
    }
    balancing();
}

public void leftRotation()
{
    NodeQ tmp=new NodeQ(-1, -1);
    tmp.deepCopy(this);
    this.deepCopy(this.right);

    if (this.left==null) tmp.right=null;
    else tmp.right=new NodeQ(this.left);
    this.left=new NodeQ(tmp);

    tmp.calcH();
    this.calcH();
}

public void rightRotation()
{
    NodeQ tmp=new NodeQ(-1, -1);
    tmp.deepCopy(this);
    this.deepCopy(this.left);

    if (this.right==null) tmp.left=null;
    else tmp.left=new NodeQ(this.right);
    this.right=new NodeQ(tmp);

    tmp.calcH();
    this.calcH();
}

public int calcBalance()
{
    int bal=0;
    if (left==null)
    {
        if (right!=null) bal=right.h;
    }
    else
    {
        if (right==null) bal=-left.h;
        else bal=right.h-left.h;
    }
    return bal;
}

public void balancing()
{
    int b=calcBalance();
    if (b==2)
    {
        if (right.calcBalance()<0) right.rightRotation();
        leftRotation();
    }
    else if (b==-2)
    {
`       if (left.calcBalance()>0) left.leftRotation();
        rightRotation();
    }
    else calcH();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply avoid copying nodes; you can balance subtrees just by assigning their **left** and **right** pointers.

Rotation functions should take the subtree root as a parameter and return the transformed subtree; rotating trees "in place" is a major unneeded complication.

Comment: Isn't that what I called "shallow copy", though? How would you go about implementing that? 
The algorithm I'm basing myself upon does a left rotation thusly: "tempNode=root; root=root.right; tempNode.right=root.left;"
The second step, in this implementation, would be this=right; which cannot be done in Java.

Comment: That's why I suggest rotating an arbitrary NodeQ passed as a parameter, not **this**

Comment: Yup.  Return the new root, rather than trying to assign to `this`; the returned node might be `this`, or it might be `right`.

Comment: Ok, yes, I had considered switching to a parameter/return which would indeed lift the problem of the "this" affectation... but at the cost of moving it to the calling function. Still, I guess I could change all of the hierarchy of functions to avoid having to do that.
But it doesn't change the "shallow copy" problem, at least in the algorithm used: the first ligne assigns the NodeQ given in parameter to the temporary NodeQ, then any modification to one (such as affecting to their left or right NodeQs) affects the other. Maybe another rotating algorithm should be used.

Comment: Tried another rotation algorithm ([the one used here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall09/V22.0102-001/programs/AVLTree/AvlTree.txt)) which also works on paper, but it creates its own problems. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's impossible to do this with a single class in Java. Guess I'll have to try a 2-class version.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to deep clone is to implement Serializable and then serialize / deserialize the object (eg to a ByteArrayOutputStream).

Comment: And that would recursively include all descendents no matter how deep?

Comment: Apart from being slow in itself, such a copy would create a lot of garbage ArrayList<Segment> and NodeQ objects.